# How put vertical columns in dynamic table? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i create a dynamic table like that:

```
'Item Number

    Dim conItem As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmdItem As New SqlCommand

    conItem = FunctionConnection()
    cmdItem.Connection = conItem
    cmdItem.CommandText = "GetItemNumber"
    cmdItem.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim ItemNumber As SqlDataReader = Nothing
    conItem.Open()
    ItemNumber = cmdItem.ExecuteReader()
    Dim Item As String = Nothing


    Do While ItemNumber.Read()

        Item = ItemNumber.GetValue(ItemNumber.GetOrdinal("ParagraphOrder"))

        'Station
        Dim conStation As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmdStation As New SqlCommand

        conStation = FunctionConnection()
        cmdStation.Connection = conStation

        cmdStation.CommandText = "GetStationValue"
        cmdStation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmdStation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParagraphOrder", Item)

        Dim RowsStation As SqlDataReader = Nothing
        conStation.Open()
        RowsStation = cmdStation.ExecuteReader()

        Dim Station As String = Nothing

        Do While RowsStation.Read()

            Station = RowsStation.GetValue(RowsStation.GetOrdinal("ActivityResource"))

            TBLCell = New TableCell
            TBLCell.Text = Station
            TBLCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
            TBLCell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            TBLCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            TBLCell.BorderWidth = 1

            TBLRow.Cells.Add(TBLCell)

            TBLCell = New TableCell
            TBLCell.Text = Item
            TBLCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
            TBLCell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            TBLCell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black
            TBLCell.BorderWidth = 1

            TBLRow.Cells.Add(TBLCell)

        Loop
        conStation.Close()
    Loop
    conItem.Close()
```

Image here:
[image]

I want my table to have 2 columns, name with number in vertical.
Two and two, not like this, one single row.

My table have been create with procedures and get a value for every cell, but i want a vertical table with two columns not a single row.

"reception of the parts" with number.
Thanks a lot

Comment: I resolved with:TablVerificari.Rows.Add(TBLRow)
            TBLRow = New TableRow

Answer (score 2):

First of all you would need to define `column names`, then you need to create the `row` that will host cells for each value. In pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
//Define table columns
var table = new Table();
//this define header titles
table.columns.add(new Column("Column 1"));
table.columns.add(new Column("Column 2"));
foreach(var object in collection)
{
     var row = new Row();
     var cell = new Cell(object.columnOneValue);
     // cell style could be define here, before it is added to its parent row.
     row.cells.add(cell);
     cell = new Cell(object.columnTwoValue);
     // cell style could be define here, before it is added to its parent row.
     row.cells.add(cell);
     table.rows.add(row);
}
```

Hope this short pseudo-code could help you with your issue.